# Using escape character to replace & with &amp; in an xml file vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, escaping, character

I am trying to replace an & in the name of a service in an xml document.

The & is causing an error. Is there anyway i can write some piece of code which will escape "&" as " & a m p ;"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using an [`XmlTextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx#Y0) to write out your XML; it will handle the escaping for you.

The code might look something like this:

```
    Dim writer As Xml.XmlTextWriter

    writer = New Xml.XmlTextWriter("C:\Temp\Services.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    writer.Formatting = Xml.Formatting.Indented

    writer.WriteStartDocument()
    writer.WriteStartElement("Services")

    For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Service) In discservice
        writer.WriteStartElement("Name")
        writer.WriteString(item.Key)
        writer.WriteElementString("DisplayName", item.Value.DisplayName)
        writer.WriteElementString("ServiceName", item.Value.ServiceName)
        writer.WriteElementString("ServiceStatus", item.Value.ServiceStatus)
        writer.WriteEndElement()
    Next

    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteEndDocument()
    writer.Close()
```

Obviously, if you're writing to a stream rather than a file, you'd need to use the other constructor for the XmlTextWriter.